# how to send two diffrent json data to android activity from php at the same time?

Tags: php, android, json

i am trying to send the json data from php file to android activity but i am not able to receive the data in onPostExecute method.

this is my json data which i try to send

```
{"NEW_SCHEDULE":[{"New_schedule_id":"40","New_year":"2018","New_month":"02","New_day":"07","New_StartTime":"1","New_Endtime":"2","New_Hours":"03:00:00"}]}{"UPDATES_SCHEDULE":[{"Update_schedule_id":"15","Update_year":"2018","Update_month":"02","Update_day":"08","Update_StartTime":"6:10 pm","Update_Endtime":"9:00 pm","Update_Hours":"01:00:00"}]}
```

in php file i send the data like this

```
 if($new_schedule==null) 
{
    echo "NO NEW SCHEDULE FOUND";
}
else
{
     echo json_encode(array("NEW_SCHEDULE"=> $new_schedule));
}
if($update_schedule ==null)
{
    echo "NO NEW UPDATES AVALIABLE";
}
else
{
     echo json_encode(array("UPDATES_SCHEDULE"=> $update_schedule));
}
```

and in android activity i try to recieve the data like this and try to send them to two diffrent activity and display them in toast ,but i dont know how to recieve two diffrent json data at the same time.

first activity

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

             try
            {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
                Intent k = new Intent(ctx, Update_Schedule.class);
                k.putExtra("rootJson",result);
                startActivity(k);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

here i want to recieve two diffrent json data and i want to send them to two diffrent activity,but i dont know how  to recieve two diffrent json data from php. can any one tell me how to do that , help me to fix this issue.

Comment: if you want to receive the NEW_SCHEDULE & UPDATES_SCHEDULE in json then put them in one array like  echo json_encode(array("NEW_SCHEDULE"=> $new_schedule, "UPDATES_SCHEDULE"=> $update_schedule ));

Comment: ok ,but how to seprate them in android activity, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Add both of them n single array and send back.

Comment: ya, i am doing that but how to seperate them in android activity because i want to send them to two diffrent activity @Purushottam zende

Comment: I am not expert in Android , but i think you can do like this 
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray new_sch =  jobj.getJSONArray("NEW_SCHEDULE");
JSONArray upt_sch =  jobj.getJSONArray("UPDATES_SCHEDULE");

Comment: ok i will try like this way